# Symfony Webpack Encore ReferenceError: function is not defined

Tags: php, webpack, symfony4, webpack-encore

I'm using Webpack Encore in my Symfony 4 application. Now issue is that my required js file is not working. Below is the code

**webpack.config.js**

```
const Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    .setPublicPath('/build')   
    .addEntry('app', './entry/app.js')

    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())   
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())   
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

**app.js**

```
require('../public/assets/js/custom/common.js');
require('../public/assets/js/page1.js');
```

**common.js**

```
function showLoader() {
    //....
}

function hideLoader() {
    //....
}

.......
```

**page1.js**

```
....
showLoader();
```

and when I use my `app.js` file in my html and run the page then it throws an error in console

```
page1.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: showLoader is not defined
    at Object../public/assets/js/page1.js (page1.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Object../entry/app.js (app.js:2)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
    at app.js?version=10:1
```

I do not want to use module.exports as my `common.js` has 50+ functions

Comment: are you not simply forgetting to import common.js on page1.js?

Comment: common.js should be import globaly not in single page that's why